# NSTableView with user-adjustable row height

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I'm looking for a way to have the user adjust the row height of an NSTableView instance by clicking and dragging on the separator line between rows.

Maybe somebody is aware of a subclass or sample code that implements such a feature. Answers are hard to find in the midst of all the dynamic row height questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's built in. Non-uniform row heights were "new" (10.3 or so) and by that time column width adjustment and saving were already set in stone, and I don't remember them being extended to cover rows.

So I think you have to display your own row headers using a vertical accessory view and hit-test and track the resizing yourself.

Comment: Uniform resizing for all rows would be fine for my use-case.